# Cassandra single node high cpu usage

Tags: java, performance, docker, cassandra

I am trying to get insights of the single node  cassandra performance.

#### My Setup: (VM)

- 4 CPU, 16GB RAM
- Hard drive : 7200 RPM

#### Worst case load:

- 16K writes per minutes

#### CPU usage:

- 40 % (Single core according to ctop)

#### More Details:

- Running cassandra inside docker
- Cassandra docker version 3.11
- Using 1 materialized view

#### Schema

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent (a text,b bigint,c bigint,
d double,e float,f double,g double,h int,i float, PRIMARY KEY(a,b));

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW p_view AS
 SELECT * FROM parent WHERE c IS NOT NULL AND b IS NOT NULL
 PRIMARY KEY(a,c,b);
```

I want to know is this expected performance? or not ?

Please let me know the input, thanks in advance

Comment: what about your table schema and key space and your hard disk drive(rpm)?

Comment: @vahidchakoshy updated question with schema and rpm details